# Can I force a user to choose the auto complete in a Rails form?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, validation, autocomplete

Right now in my Rails app a user can type in anything in a form or choose from the auto complete list that comes up. Is there a way to force the user to choose something from the list e.g. a validation?

Comment: You mean like a drop down list?

Comment: Yes, when a user starts typing a location a jquery plugin brings up options via a drop down list that the user can choose or just type in anything in the form if he wants and then post. Any help?

Comment: Are you using `jquery-tokeninput` or something else for this purpose?

Comment: The gem for locations auto complete used is the jquery address picker!

Answer (score 1):

This is not the same as dropdown list. Imagine you pick a tag in Stackoverflow, this should be similar, though SO doesn't prevent you from picking a weired tag nobody has seen.

And it's definitely possible with Javascript validation.

You just catch the event when the text field lost focus. Now you can do two things:

1. Your app pick the first matching value as the input. For example, the user input "fac", and there are options for "facebook", "facetime", "faceblah". If the user don't continue to input and lost focus, the value will end up with "faceblah" the first choice.
2. What if the user leave focus with an invalid value? Say "fad", this matching none result. You check if the input value is within the returned JSON array. If not, a warning will appear showing the input is invalid. And you add some cretieria to prevent this form to be actually submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery-TokenInput and limit the number of tokens to 1.

Just watch this railscasts, you will figure it out.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields

Comment: Token fields not cutting it!

Comment: I'm not working with Tokens, the autocomplete plugin is called address_picker-rails gem. Check out http://airlifteauto.herokuapp.com/posts/new to see what the list looks like. Just start typing any Town/City name.